# Python: Remove “mid-row” line breaks in CSV

Tags: python

I have a csv generated by a platform we use at work with 86 different fields. The number of fields or “columns” should remain static. The fields are a mix of data types, but some of them have free-form text that contain line breaks.

The issue is that when I import the csv into any program (Excel, notepad, Jupyter Notebook with Python), the free-form text fields are broken into a new row (or multiple new rows if the field contains multiple line breaks).

I’ve tried a number of things suggested by various threads here, but none have really been applicable to what I’m doing.

Here’s an example of the format of what I have in the platform and want in csv (the actual data is more complex, but just to illustrate the issue)(the \n included below is to illustrate where the actual breaks are, but they are not actually visible in the editor (unless searching for them)):

```
Header0, H1, H2, H86
Name0, ABC, 123, “Hello\n my name is ABC.\n I live at 123.”\n
Name1, DEF, 456, “Hello\n my name is DEF.\n I live at 456.”\n
Name2, GHI, 789, “Good bye”\n
```

When I import this into any text editor, Excel, Jupyter with Python using pandas, etc. I get:

```
Header0, H1, H2, H86
Name0, ABC, 123, “Hello\n
my name is ABC.,,,\n
I live at 123.”,,,\n
Name1, DEF, 456, “Hello\n
my name is DEF.,,,\n
I live at 456.”,,,\n
Name2, GHI, 789, “Good bye”\n
```

Suggestions have been to remove all line breaks, but that doesn’t work because I’d then be removing the legitimate line breaks at the end of each row (otherwise, how would separate rows be designated in the csv? <— not rhetorical, correct me if I’m wrong).

A workaround I’ve been thinking of is to write a script that iterates through the csv, counting commas and adding each item separated by the commas to a dataframe until it hits 86 commas, then starts adding to the next row in the data frame. But I’d need help actually writing that.

Final note, upon generating the CSV from the platform, commas are removed from all fields, so the only commas in the CSV are those being used as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        outfile.writerow([c.replace('\n', '') for c in row])
```

Comment: The issue with that is that even as it is right now, the single valid row has been broken into multiple rows to begin with. It’s an issue with the way the CSV is generated. What should be row 1 has been broken up into multiple rows because certain fields on the platform contained text that contained line breaks. When the CSV is generated from the platform, the line breaks from the text fields cause that record to be split into multiple rows.

Comment: I can't really say much more past "play with `quotechar` and `linenterminator`)